# getting error while using string.punctuation python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, punctuation

I tried to use string.punctuation function in python.I doing it in python 3.5 version. This is my following code:

```
import string
def check(text):
    x=set(text.punctuation())
```

I am getting following error

```
'str' object has no attribute 'punctuation'
```

PLease help with the correct way of using this.I even tried using ispunct() fucntion.

I tried for solving this as shown in the link below,but couldn't figure it out.

[Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: did you miss the `import string` in the question and answers you linked to?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention . i did added import string while running the code

Answer (score 6):

`punctuation` is a method of `string` module not a string object attribute.

```
>>> import string
>>> 
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

If you want to get the `punctuation` from a text you can use a generator  expression within `set` :

```
set(i for i in text if i in string.punctuation)
```